# Execute operation on Future's value for its side effects, discarding result and retaining original value, but retaining order of operation

Tags: scala, future, scala-cats

Say I have the following operations that must proceed *in order*:

1. Get blog post
2. Post analytics
3. Forward blog post

In code it may look like this:

```
val blogPostFut: Future[BlogPost] = blogService.getPost(postId)
val afterAnalytics: Future[BlogPost] = blogPostFut.flatMap(blogPost =>
  val ignoredResponse: Future[Analytics] = analyticsService.sendAnalytics(blogPost)
  ignoredResponse.map(_ => blogPost)  // <-- THIS BOTHERS ME
)
val finalValue: Future[ForwardResult] = afterAnalytics.flatMap(blogPost =>
  forwardService.forward(blogPost)
)
```

I am bothered that, in order to ensure proper ordering of execution, I have to pass forward `blogPost` within `ignoredResponse` in order to ensure it is available for step 3.

I'd love if I could do something like this:

```
blogPostFut.magicalFlatMap(analyticsService.sendAnalytics)
```

Where `magicalFlatMap` might be implemented like so:

```
// pseudocode
def magicalFlatMap[A,B](f: A => Future[B]): Future[A] = f().map(_ => this.value)
```

Does `magicalFlatMap` exist in either the Scala stdlib or in Cats? Is it possible to `map` a `Future` for side effects while automatically retaining the value of the original `Future` and strict ordering of operations?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`Future.andThen`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/948da0358c53933100fa643a0f9d841ac4dcfb34/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L498) for side-effects

```
for {
  blogPost <- blogService.getPost(postId).andThen { case Success(post) => analyticsService.sendAnalytics(post) }
  finalValue <- forwardService.forward(blogPost)
} yield {
  finalValue
}
```

Here is a dummy example

```
  val result = for {
    v1 <- Future(1)
    v2 <- Future(v1 + 2).andThen { case  Success(v) => println(v) }
    v3 <- Future(v1 + v2)
  } yield {
    v3
  }

  result.foreach(println)
```

which should output

```
3
4
```

We could also do

```
for {
  blogPost   <- blogService.getPost(postId) 
  _          <- analyticsService.sendAnalytics(blogPost)
  finalValue <- forwardService.forward(blogPost)
} yield {
  finalValue
}
```

however in this case failure in `analyticsService.sendAnalytics(blogPost)` would short-circuit the whole for-comprehension which might not be desirable.

Comment: Wouldn’t this remove the guarantee that step 3 happens *after* step 2?

Comment: My understanding is step 3 is still guaranteed to happen after step 2 due to nature of for-comprehension.

Comment: The java doc on the method does seem to confirm this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`magicalFlatMap` seems to be `cats.FlatMap#flatTap`

https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/FlatMap.scala#L150